# Change qty of order items in magento

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7, magento-1.9, magento-1.8

i trying to reduce qty of some order item programmatically but changes not applying. Here is my try:

```
    require_once('../app/Mage.php');
    umask(0);
    Mage::app();
    $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($_POST['order_id']);
    foreach($order->getAllItems() as $item) {
        $item->setQtyOrdered($item->getQtyOrdered() - 1)->save();
    }
    $order->setStatus("complete");       
    $history = $order->addStatusHistoryComment('Order was set to Complete by our automation tool.', false);
    $history->setIsCustomerNotified(false);
    $order->save();
```

Comment: what's wrong with that code? if you loop again the items you'll see that qty_ordered has been decreased...

Answer (score 0):

You try this

```
<?php
         $order_id = 2314; //use your own order id 
         $order = Mage::getModel("sales/order")->load($order_id);
       //load order by order id 
         $ordered_items = $order->getAllItems();
           foreach($ordered_items as $item){     //item detail 
               $item->setQtyOrdered($item->getQtyOrdered() - 1)->save();
            } 
         $order->setStatus("complete");       
         $history = $order->addStatusHistoryComment('Order was set to Complete by our automation tool.', false);
         $history->setIsCustomerNotified(false);
         $order->save();

    ?>
```